# How to test the opposite of assert_text in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, testunit, ruby-on-rails-6

I want to be sure my page does not contain certain text, I know there is an `assert_text` function, but, how do I test the opposite?

I am using RoR 6.0, the default test framework (I think it is Test Unit) and capybara

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rails 6 is using [Minitest](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#rails-meets-minitest) and [Capybara](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#system-testing) by default.

`assert_text` comes from [Capybara](http://teamcapybara.github.io/capybara/), or to be more precise, from [`Capybara::Minitest::Assertions`](https://rubydoc.info/github/teamcapybara/capybara/master/Capybara/Minitest/Assertions).

As you can see in [`Capybara::Minitest::Assertions`](https://rubydoc.info/github/teamcapybara/capybara/master/Capybara/Minitest/Assertions), there is an assertion called [`assert_no_text`](https://rubydoc.info/github/teamcapybara/capybara/master/Capybara/Minitest/Assertions#assert_no_text-instance_method), which, I suppose, does exactly what you need.

Further details can be found [here](https://rubydoc.info/github/teamcapybara/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers#assert_no_text-instance_method).

And this is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33982933/12201472) to a quick explanation of the difference between [`Test::Unit`](https://github.com/test-unit/test-unit) and [`Minitest`](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest).

Hope this helps.